# Alternative terms for Men's and Women's T-shirts?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, gender-neutral, canadian-english

I'm going to be hosting an event that may include gender non-binary participants, and we have some t-shirts to give away.  They are manufactured in Men's and Women's cuts.

Are there any terms that can refer to these cuts without using gender names?  The terms would need to be understood in Canada (which I am fairly new to).

Comment: ***T*** and ***NT***.  The meaning is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Mostly just confuses things, but: https://www.looksgud.in/blog/different-types-of-t-shirts-men/

Comment: Are you going to go against the apparel industry's nomenclature??  men's apparel or clothing; women's apparel or clothing; children's apparel or clothing. T-shirt shapes. gender identity is one thing; body shape is another.

Comment: I don't think people are going to object to you calling them "Men's" and "Women's" as long as you don't restrict who can choose which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These styles are also called **straight cut** and **fitted** respectively:

> There are two main styles of t-shirts available: straight cut, often known as "men's" or "unisex", and fitted cut, also known as "women's".
>   <sub>[T-Shirts — Geek Feminism Wiki](http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/T-shirts)</sub>

Comment: You do get fitted t-shirts specifically for men (i.e. those cut to be very close to a man's body), although they're also known as "muscle fit" or "slim fit". A man's fitted shirt will be different to a woman's, owing to the different body shape. But I agree straight cut/fitted is probably as good as you can get.

Comment: the apparel industry uses men and women so I would not put those in quotation marks. gender identify is one thing; clothing terminology another.

Comment: :^) And my wall socket is female, and the plug that goes into it is male.

Comment: *Fitted*, in this context, means only that the garment is designed so as to fit the body of the wearer closely, as opposed to hanging on it loosely; it does not convey anything as to what the shape is that the garment fits. I thus doubt that the word would be understood by an average person to have the meaning that is intended here (particularly if the person is familiar with its use for certain kinds of (what has been traditionally classified as) men's clothing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't condone political correctness as a fad but how about Triangle and Hour Glass. I'll leave it to the reader to figure out (no pun intended) which is male and which is female.

I'm not sure I like the other answer where females get "fitted" shirts implying that men get shirts that don't fit. From the other point of view males get "straight cut" and females are left with "not cut straight".

Comment: "fitted", as a dictionary would tell you, means "made to fit the shape of something" and has nothing to do with whether something fits or doesn't fit.

Comment: @StuartF So, every t-shirt is equally "fitted?" Since every t-shirt would fit an object shaped like its inside.